# AWS amplify manual deployment error in Web app

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, vue.js, continuous-integration, aws-amplify

i have an unsolvable issue for me
i have a web app written with vueJS 2
one part of my app interact with API gateway (direct DynamoDB and some lambda)

my app is to huge to be automatically deploued with the repository connection from amplify so i update it manaually

My pipe is as following
when pushed on preprod branch, it triggers a pipeline that execute a npm install and npm run build  with node 16:15:0-slim base image
once the build is complet it pushes as zip folder the content of my dist to an S3 bucket.
Finally i make an aws amplify start-deployement command with my S3 key

The whole process works fine and i see throught the console that my app is uptodate.
When i use it and only on some particular parts i receive an error

```
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not parse content for https://XXXXXXX.YYYYYYYYY.fr/js/899.5b9eab10.js.map: Unexpected token '<', "<!doctype "... is not valid JSON
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not parse content for https://XXXXXXX.YYYYYYYYY.fr/js/996.92a6db40.js.map: Unexpected token '<', "<!doctype "... is not valid JSON
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not parse content for https://XXXXXXX.YYYYYYYYY.fr/js/358.3dc9e035.js.map: Unexpected token '<', "<!doctype "... is not valid JSON
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not parse content for https://XXXXXXX.YYYYYYYYY.fr/js/601.c43c3544.js.map: Unexpected token '<', "<!doctype "... is not valid JSON
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not parse content for https://XXXXXXX.YYYYYYYYY.fr/js/41.9910dc6e.js.map: Unexpected token '<', "<!doctype "... is not valid JSON
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not parse content for https://XXXXXXX.YYYYYYYYY.fr/js/606.907e774f.js.map: Unexpected token '<', "<!doctype "... is not valid JSON
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not parse content for https://XXXXXXX.YYYYYYYYY.fr/js/283.13d9e03f.js.map: Unexpected token '<', "<!doctype "... is not valid JSON
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not parse content for https://XXXXXXX.YYYYYYYYY.fr/js/982.339fbacd.js.map: Unexpected token '<', "<!doctype "... is not valid JSON
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not parse content for https://XXXXXXX.YYYYYYYYY.fr/js/57.34d7149e.js.map: Unexpected token '<', "<!doctype "... is not valid JSON
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not parse content for https://XXXXXXX.YYYYYYYYY.fr/js/502.23abe13e.js.map: Unexpected token '<', "<!doctype "... is not valid JSON
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not parse content for https://XXXXXXX.YYYYYYYYY.fr/js/311.25a1098b.js.map: Unexpected token '<', "<!doctype "... is not valid JSON
```

When using it in vue-cli-service serve --https true everything works fine

When using it and build it locally and use http serve it also work fine

i can't figure it out why yhe browser expects to find  tag in compiled js file

Thanks for the help and advices